# Is it possible to generate a Chatter post in code in the same format as a CreateRecordEvent type?

Tags: community, chatter

Looking at FeedItem records in SOQL, I see that a system generated Chatter post when a new record is created is of Type = 'CreateRecordEvent'.  Is there a way to emulate this style in code? Salesforce does not allow DML insert of this Type.

Under simpler circumstances, a LinkPost FeedItem would suffice (though not as nice looking).  However, the record and its Chatter feed are available in a Community, so the LinkPost (see code below) with its explicitly defined url would point a Community User to the SFDC org they may not have access to.  Conversely, an explicitly set url with the Community path would not be ideal for the user working inside the org.

```
FeedItem tempFeedItem = new FeedItem(
    IsRichText = true,
    LinkUrl = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+newRecord.Id,
    ParentId = caseRecord.Id,
    Status = 'Published',
    Type = 'LinkPost',
    Visibility = 'AllUsers'
);

insert tempFeedItem;
```

The longer version of what I'm trying to achieve is that I'm trying to create FeedItems for multiple records in a trigger before moving on to additional steps of adding FeedComments under each.

Comment: Have you tried using a relative URL instead? `LinkUrl = '/'+newRecord.Id,`

Comment: @AayushK - yes, unfortunately, on the community side the rest of the url does not automatically resolve so it just appends that id to the base url without the additional sub levels it needs to resolve there (i.e. something like baseurl/communityname/s/objectname/recordid)